# Асинхронный постинг локальных фото в telegraph

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, aiogram, asyncio, aiohttp

У меня есть до 10 фотографий отправленных юзером, мне нужно асинхронно создать статью изагрузить иx с локальной машины на telegraph. Как? Спасибо

```
import asyncio

from telegraph import Telegraph
from html_telegraph_poster import upload_image

telegraph = Telegraph()

telegraph.create_account(short_name='Queen')

async def create_photo_albom(id_user:int, name:str, photo_albom:list):

    html = f'<h4>Альбом пользователя {name}</h4><br>'
    dirr = 'photo/'
    for photo in photo_albom:
        html+=f"<img src='{upload_image(dirr+photo)}'/><br>"

    response = telegraph.create_page(
    f'{id_user}',
    html_content=html)

    return ('http://telegra.ph/{}'.format(response['path']))
```

Comment: А что не работает? Код `html+=f"<img src='{upload_image(dirr+photo)}'/><br>"` выглядит правдоподобно.... Хотел предложить картинки в html поместить как `data:image/;base64`, но у вас уже есть решение. Или вопрос о том как скачать, отправленные пользователем, чтобы их в `photo_albom` передать?

Comment: Вопрос в том, что telegraph и html_telegraph_poster стопают мое асинхронное приложение, они дожны рабоать в 1 loop

Comment: Ваш комментарий бы в вопрос, это все объясняет :) Тут или искать асинхронные версии этих библиотек, или самому переписывать, или сделать через потоки, т.е. код с upload_image и create_page выполнять в потоке, а в create_photo_albom ожидать пока ответ не будет готов

Comment: да, но вот как это сделать) я нашел aio-telegraph, но он откзывается постить почему-то, да и библиотека по загрузке стопает) мне хотелось бы готовое решение)) ладно, провозился несколько часов и без результатно

Comment: ` стопают мое асинхронное ` - запускай в экзекуторе.

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio

from aiograph import Telegraph

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
telegraph = Telegraph()


async def main():
    await telegraph.create_account('aiograph-demo')
    page = await telegraph.create_page('Demo', '<p><strong>Hello, world!</strong></p>')
    print('Created page:', page.url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(telegraph.close())  # Close the aiohttp.ClientSession
```

Comment: Добавьте текста о том что Вы сделали.